# How to represent a 'long' number as nodes in a linked-list [JAVA]

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list

I have a pragmatic task to solve:

Int and Long numbers that we can store in memory cells
are limited in size. One way to solve the problem would be to set up a linked-list in which each node in the list will contain one digit from the number so that the number itself will not be kept as a number but as a collection of its' digits- one after the other.

I have to create a Constructor, which gets a 'long' type of number and stores it in a format of a linked list.

By that I mean that if we take the number 233,674,318 , the Constructor would create a representation of this number as the following : 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1 -> 8

Could you please suggest me how can I approach this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the BigDecimal class to represent the number? That would be an existing solution and more efficient. Or you could represent the number of a collection of Integer or Byte values rather than decimal digits. Decimal digits are only an artifact of how we view numbers, not a property of them. The binary groupings are more of a property of how the numbers are stored and hence more natural.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a number's least significant digit (the one on the right) using the modulo operator. In this case, `233,674,318 % 10` will yield 8 (`%` signifies modulo). You can get rid of a number's least significant digit using division. `233,674,318 / 10` will yield 23,367,431 which is like removing the 8 from the number. Using these two operations you can extract all the digits from a number and build a list out of them.

Comment: I see how it can work. I do want to ask, how can I add the digit that I extracted to a node , so that it would be : 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 - > 4 -> 3 -> 1 -> 8 and not : 8 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4-> 7 -> 6 -> 3 -> 3 -> 2

Comment: You can only use the modulo operator on numbers which already fit into long or int in this case though, rendering the whole linked list approach a little pointless...

Comment: @MaxGorohovski When you add elements to the list, you should be able to add them at the start of the list.

Comment: @BeUndead He said their constructor gets a long, not a string or anything. They'll probably implement basic arithmetic on these numbers later and then they'll be able to go over the 64-bit limit.

Comment: No argument here, which is why I haven’t downvoted or anything. You’ve answered the question, but in a way that will break on the extension of the class to its actual use-case. My comment was more directed at Max as something to think about before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to String and take each char to create nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*

         LinkedList<Integer> getList(long num){
             String[] arr = String.valueOf(num).split("");
             LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
             list.addAll(Stream.of(arr)
                     .mapToInt(x->Integer.parseInt(x))
                     .boxed()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
             return list;
         }
```

This is a method you could use. Ultimately, it is a matter of either using the modulus to get every digit or using a split function on the String value of the long number to be then parsed and stored in a LinkedList of Integers.

If you are trying to save memory, as per your question, using integers for the linkedlist would be better as integers only use 32 bits whereas long uses 64 bits.